# QGIS SCP pulgin layer output

Tags: qgis, layers, classification, accuracy, scp

I use the plugin regularly and have already used every function. But I have often noticed that the output layers are not always intuitively understandable.
I googled on the topic and found no definition of the result layers. Incidentally, there is no information about the output in the manual.

For example, I am interested in the exact definition of accuracyoutputlayer.tif. the values ​​and their range are not clear to me.  Or after a normal classification, some layer for each class are also created. The meaning of the values ​​is not clear to me too.

Do you have any information?